# Entire Website Shrink to fit browser window?

Tags: html, css, browser, shrink

I would like my HTML website to automatically shrink entirely (images, text and all) when loaded in different size browser windows.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. http://www.studiojordan.com/site.html

I understand this website is flash I'm wondering if this can be accomplished with CSS?

I'm new to coding, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like Elliot said, you can't do that. Aside from the `window.open()` solution, you may style your website differently for any resolution you want to support. This is accomplished through **media queries**, which are part of **css3**, and are very much supported by every major browser to date. You can read more about them [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/), [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), and [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries), just to name a few places. Also, this is part of what is nowadays called [Responsive Web Design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to change the size of the browser window with CSS or Javascript, unfortunately. You can, however, resize a window opened with `window.open()`. This won't do any good though as your browser's popup blocker will [almost always] prevent such a window from opening (I did read somewhere that if the window opening was a direct result of a user action it wouldn't be blocked, but I'm not sure...).

**tl;dr**:
No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you get to that is sizing and positioning everything with relative units (like `%` and `em`). But that has limitations, and can get really intricate. So it's actually media queries, as Julian suggested, or nothing!